# Geometric Interpretation of a function

Tags: geometry, functions

Look at the following functions:
$$l(x)=x/\sqrt{1+x^2}$$
$$k(x)=x/\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
These functions give a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(-1,1)$. Can someone give a geometric interpretation of this functions? I think it has somthing in common with circles but I don't know.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: wolfram alpha will be your friend ;)

Comment: I would try $x=tan \theta$ and $x= sin \theta$

Answer (score 1):

Let me describe $k$ geometrically; its inverse $l$ gets an interpretation at the same time.

Imagine the real axis as the $x$-axis in the plane and let $C$ be the circle of radius one centered at $(0,1)$.
Take a point $x\in(-1,1)$.
Consider the point $(x,1-\sqrt{1-x^2})$ on the circle $C$.
(You can imagine lifting the point $(x,0)$ from the line to the circle above it.)
Now take the line $L$ that passes through $(x,1-\sqrt{1-x^2})$ and $(0,1)$, the center of $C$.
This line intersects the $x$-axis at a point $(y,0)$.
It is a simple exercise to see that $y=k(x)$.

These functions are indeed related to a circle in this sense.
Or, in fact, a semicircle since we only ever used the lower half of $C$.

You can describe the inverse function $l$ in a similar way be doing the construction backwards: start from a point $(x,0)$ on the line, join it to $(0,1)$ and see where the line segment connecting these points meets $C$, and then project it down to the $x$-axis.